# express API / react issue with routing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem where the **appropriate routes are not being used** in my React front end / express server API app. 
Fetch requests from react work as they should, as do requests from Postman.

**My problem is**: when *accessing the api routes from the browser, the react app is always sent*.

**Routes**

`GET /api/new`
Takes one param `url` ie `http://www.youtube.com`
Sample request:
`api/new?url=http://www.youtube.com`

**Response**
e.g. 
`{short_link: http://localhost:8080/api/150}`  (150 being a unique ID.)

`GET /api/:id`
Takes one param `id`  A unique number, e.g. 150
Sample request:
`api/150`

**Response**

1. Looks up id in DB, finds the short link
2. `res.redirect(http://www.youtube.com)`

Heres my [repo](https://github.com/mrslwiseman/shrinkthis)

```
// server/index.js
const routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);

// server/routes/index.js
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/build')));

router.use('/api/new', catchErrors(link.setLink)) 
router.use('/api/:id', catchErrors(link.getLink)) 
router.use('/api/', catchErrors(index)) 

// All remaining requests return the front end
router.use('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: question made more clear, please remove down vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cracked it!

My problem was that I had this line of code in my main app file:

```
// server/index.js
app.use('/', routes);
```

Which I thought would just direct it to my routes file:

```
// server/routes/index.js
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/build')));

router.use('/api/new', catchErrors(link.setLink)) 
router.use('/api/:id', catchErrors(link.getLink)) 
router.use('/api/', catchErrors(index)) 

// All remaining requests return the front end
router.use('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Fixed by changing:

```
// server/index.js
app.use('/', routes);
```

to

```
// server/index.js
app.use(routes);
```

The routes werent working because `/ + /api/` isnt a valid route!

Any further clarification on this much appreciated in my learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902824/express-js-calling-2-get-methods/48904633#48904633) where your express routes are conflicting.

You're telling your application to serve static content as your first route. I believe express routes are filtered through in the order that they're created, therefore I expect you're getting the top line executing and then the request completing instead of filtering down into the /api endpoints you want.

You should try moving your top line underneath your `router.use('/api'...);` code. This should attach your static assets after the API endpoints and I think this should fix the issue.

Comment: i checked out your answer to the other question and that helped me gain more insight into routing, thank you!.

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted by someone, would be great if they could leave a comment explaining what I could do better :)